# Having issues with positioning elements on website

Tags: css, html, drop-down-menu, position

I'm having a few issues with the website I'm coding, and I can't find answers to them. First, here is the HTML code of the page I'm having issues with, and the code of the CSS linked to it:

> HTML:
>
> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
> <head>
> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/test.css">
> <title>Capturing Life - Kim Chaffin Photography</title>
> </head>
> <body>
> <div id="bg2">
> <center>
> <div id="logo">
> <img src="../Pictures/logo.png" width="511" height="207" alt="Load Error">
> </div>
> </center>
> <center>
> <div id="flourish">
> <img src="../Pictures/flourish2.png" width="462px" height="329px" alt="Load Error">
> </div>
> </center>
> <center>
> <div id="header">
> <svg>
> <rect x="100" y="100" rx="20" ry="20" width="1096" height="230"     style="fill:#625D5D;stroke:#625D5D;stroke-width:5;opacity:1"/>
> </svg>
> </div>
> </center>
> <center>
> <div id="headerfix">
> <svg>
> <rect x="100" y="300" width="1096" height="100"     style="fill:#625D5D;stroke:#625D5D;stroke-width:5;opacity:1"/>
> </svg>
> </div>
> </center>
> <center>
> <div id="tabbox">
> <svg>
> <rect x="100" y="300" width="1096" height="50"     style="fill:#625D5D;stroke:#625D5D;stroke-width:5;opacity:1"/>
> </svg>
> </div>
> </center>
> <center>
> <div id="tabs">
> <ul type=none>
> <table width="80%">
> <tr>
> <td>
> <ul>
> <a href="Home.html"><img src="../Pictures/Kim Photography_1.png"     onmouseover="this.src='../Pictures/Kim Photography on mouseover_1.png'" 
> onmouseout="this.src='../Pictures/Kim Photography_1.png';" alt="Load Error" /></a> 
> <script type="text/javascript"> 
> img=new Image(); 
> img.src= "../Pictures/Kim Photography on mouseover_1.png";
> </script>
> </td>
> <td>
> <a href="About Kim.html"><img style="border:0px;" src="../Pictures/Kim     Photography_2.png" onmouseover="this.src='../Pictures/Kim Photography on mouseover_2.png'" 
> onmouseout="this.src='../Pictures/Kim Photography_2.png';" alt="Load Error" /></a> 
> <script type="text/javascript"> 
> img=new Image(); 
> img.src= "../Pictures/Kim Photography on mouseover_2.png";
> </script>
> </td>
> <td onmouseover="showmenu('portfolios')" onmouseout="hidemenu('portfolios')">
> <a href="Portfolios.html"><img style="border:0px;" src="../Pictures/Kim     Photography_3.png" onmouseover="this.src='../Pictures/Kim Photography on mouseover_3.png'" 
> onmouseout="this.src='../Pictures/Kim Photography_3.png';" alt="Load Error" /></a> 
> <script type="text/javascript"> 
> img=new Image(); 
> img.src= "../Pictures/Kim Photography on mouseover_3.png";
> </script>
> <br>
> <table class="menu" id="portfolios" width="124px" rules="cols">
> <tr><td class="menu"><a href="portfolios/maternity.html"><center><b>Maternity</b>    </center></a></td></tr>
> <tr><td class="menu"><a href="portfolios/little ones.html"><center><b>Little Ones</b>    </center></a></td></tr>
> <tr><td class="menu"><a href="portfolios/teens.html"><center><b>Teens</b></center></a>    </td></tr>
> <tr><td class="menu"><a href="portfolios/families.html"><center><b>Families</b>    </center></a></td></tr>
> <tr><td class="menu"><a href="portfolios/events.html"><center><b>Events</b></center>    </a></td></tr>
> <tr><td class="menu2"><a href="portfolios/pets.html"><center><b>Pets</b></center></a>    </td></tr>
> </table>
> </td>
> <td onmouseover="showmenu('sessions')" onmouseout="hidemenu('sessions')">
> <a href="Sessions.html"><img style="border:0px;" src="../Pictures/Kim     Photography_4.png" onmouseover="this.src='../Pictures/Kim Photography on mouseover_4.png'" 
> onmouseout="this.src='../Pictures/Kim Photography_4.png';" alt="Load Error" /></a> 
> <script type="text/javascript"> 
> img=new Image(); 
> img.src= "../Pictures/Kim Photography on mouseover_4.png";
> </script>
> <br>
> <table class="menu" id="sessions" width="121px" rules="cols">
> <tr><td class="menu"><a href="sessions/mini.html"><center><b>Mini-Sessions</b></center>    </a></td></tr>
> <tr><td class="menu"><a href="sessions/full.html"><center><b>Full Sessions</b></center>    </a></td></tr>
> <tr><td class="menu"><a href="sessions/newborns.html"><center><b>Newborns</b></center>    </a></td></tr>
> <tr><td class="menu2"><a href="sessions/slice.html"><center><b>Slice of Life</b>    </center></a></td></tr>
> </table>
> </td>
> <td onmouseover="showmenu('workshops')" onmouseout="hidemenu('workshops')">
> <a href="Workshops.html"><img style="border:0px;" src="../Pictures/Kim     Photography_5.png" onmouseover="this.src='../Pictures/Kim Photography on mouseover_5.png'" 
> onmouseout="this.src='../Pictures/Kim Photography_5.png';" alt="Load Error" /></a> 
> <script type="text/javascript"> 
> img=new Image(); 
> img.src= "../Pictures/Kim Photography on mouseover_5.png";
> </script>
> <br>
> <table class="menu" id="workshops" width="143px" rules="cols">
> <tr><td class="menu"><a href="workshops/slr.html"><center><b>SLR</b></center></a></td>    </tr>
> <tr><td class="menu"><a href="workshops/quick tips.html"><center><b>Quick Tips</b>    </center></a></td></tr>
> <tr><td class="menu2"><a href="workshops/documenting life.html"><center><b>Documenting     Life</b></center></a></td></tr>
> </table>
> </td>
> <td>
> <a href="Client Galleries.html"><img style="border:0px;" src="../Pictures/Kim     Photography_6.png" onmouseover="this.src='../Pictures/Kim Photography on mouseover_6.png'" 
> onmouseout="this.src='../Pictures/Kim Photography_6.png';" alt="Load Error" /></a> 
> <script type="text/javascript"> 
> img=new Image(); 
> img.src= "../Pictures/Kim Photography on mouseover_6.png";
> </script>
> </td>
> <td>
> <a href="Contact.html"><img style="border:0px;" src="../Pictures/Kim Photography_7.png"     onmouseover="this.src='../Pictures/Kim Photography on mouseover_7.png'" 
> onmouseout="this.src='../Pictures/Kim Photography_7.png';" alt="Load Error" /></a> 
> <script type="text/javascript"> 
> img=new Image(); 
> img.src= "../Pictures/Kim Photography on mouseover_7.png";
> </script>
> </td>
> </tr>
> <li>
> </ul>
> </table>
> </ul>
> </div>
> </center>
> </div>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```
>
> CSS:
>
> ```
> body
> {
> background-image:url('../Pictures/Black dot 2.png');
> background-attachment:fixed;
> font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
> }    
> table
> a
> {
> color:black;
> text-decoration:none;
> }
> a:hover
> {
> color:#FFFFFF;
> }
> td.menu
> {
> background-color:#625D5D;
> }
> td.menu2
> {
> background-color:#625D5D;
> border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
> border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
>     -moz-border-radius-bottomright:10px;
>     -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:10px;
>     -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
>     -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
> }
> table.menu
> {
> font-size:100%;
> position:absolute;
> visibility:hidden;
> }
> #bg2
> {
> background:#FFFFFF;
> background:rgba(255,255,255,1);
> width:90%;
> height:90%;
> margin:4em auto;
> }
> #header
> {
> position:relative;
> top:-545px;
> }
> #headerfix
> {
> position:relative;
> top:-1265px;
> }
> #tabbox
> {
> position:relative;
> top:-1770px;
> }
> #tabs
> {
> position:absolute;
> }
> #flourish
> {
> position:relative;
> top:-150px;
> right:340px;
> z-index:+1;
> }
> #logo
> {
> position:relative;
> top:113px;
> right:-240px;
> z-index:+1;
> }
> ```

These are the problems I'm having:

> 1. The code will not allow me to move the navigation tabs (`div id="tabs"`), which are stuck at the bottom of the page. If I apply any movement properties (`i.e. "top:-1000px;"`), the tabs disappear entirely instead of moving where I wish them to.
> 2. The white background (`div id="bg2"`) causes the elements `div id="header"`, `div id="headerfix"`, `div id="logo"`, `div id="flourish"`, and `div id="tabbox"` to be pushed down and to the right, as opposed to the top and center position I want them to be in.
> 3. The navigation tabs `Portfolios`, `Sessions`, and `Workshops` are *supposed* to have drop-down menus under them. However, the menus simply don't appear for some reason.

I *think* those are the only problems I am currently having. However, if anyone finds any other problems in my code, I'd much appreciate it if you tell me.

Comment: Could you please put that in jsfiddle or jsbin?

Comment: frenchie, jsfiddle won't display it right, because I'm currently using images stored in my computer.
Yes, jmeas, yes it does.

Comment: You're going to have a hard time finding someone to unravel that mess of code (no indentation, deprecated and potentially invalid markup, tables for layout, inline JavaScript and styles, etc.).  There's so much going wrong here, try validating both your HTML and CSS.

Comment: Sigh, I realize my code is a mess. It's organized in my mind, and that's all that matters when I'm coding, but I guess I should've fixed it when I pasted it on here.

Comment: @TimmyChaffin actually the fact that's organized in your mind is not all that matters. If you want to improve your coding skill and create larger and more complex applications, you are laying a poor foundation for that. As the complexity of your code increases, your ability to remember it decreases. With messy code, your ability to scan quickly and track down errors is greatly diminished. AND, if you hand your project off to someone else in the future, they will hate you forever. :)

Comment: @JakeParis That's true...I suppose I just got in a bad habit of doing it messy from the get-go, and never got out of that habit. I'll try to be more organized in the future.

Comment: if your site has images hosted on your computer, then just upload them to any free image hosting site, get the url and put in jsfiddle.. creating a jsfiddle is key to getting a quick and accurate response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, it looks like you have code errors in your HTML, concerning your < ul >.  You should definitely make sure your tags are nested properly since this might be one of the causes of your problems.  Also, there are 8 JavaScript errors on the page as you have it presented here.

1. Your #tabs div moves to the top for me when I use top: 0px; as it ought to.  I'm not quite sure what trouble you are having with it.
2. Your white background appears to be containing the other divs, so that would not be moving your items around anywhere.
3. Without a live, working demo with images that we can view, there's not much we can do to troubleshoot this for you.  Also, using tables for a drop-down navigation is inviting a whole slew of problems all on its own - you should consider switching to divs or a structured < ul >.

Comment: Thank you for the tips, Tammy. Now that I think about it, that was a stupid mistake on my part. I should've realized that you'd really need a working demo to view in order to really help me. Can you explain what you mean by "make sure your tags are nested properly"? Because I'm not sure I understand you. Again, can you explain how I'd go about using divs or a structured `<ul>` for the drop-down navigation?

Comment: Also, what are these 8 JavaScript errors? JavaScript definitely isn't my forte, so it doesn't surprise me that I've made mistakes.

Comment: Not a problem!  Here are a few examples of the HTML tag errors:

ul type=none needs quotes, the table inside #tabs is structured incorrectly, you have an opened < li > with no close tag and an end < ul > right under it...you need to make sure that first, your table is completely correct and then that your ul is, also.

Comment: Without being able to see how you want the nav to work, it would be hard to give you a true example, but really, you would just use floated li tags inside a ul or floated divs instead of table cells.  Here are a bunch of examples:  http://sixrevisions.com/design-showcase-inspiration/50-examples-of-drop-down-navigation-menus-in-web-designs/

If you need more one-on-one help, feel free to email me!

Comment: I've fixed everything, except that I'm having issues with the ul drop-down menus. I can't figure out how to correctly code the CSS to go along with the HTML ul menus. (I would've emailed you at this point, except that I don't know where to find your email on this site; it doesn't appear to be on your profile, or at least not visible to me.)

Comment: Never mind, I've fixed the tables and I've got everything working fine now. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad you were able to get it going!  My email is mizziness (at) gmail (dot) com if you ever need more direct help.